# How to maximize the total auction price for a set of bids subject to bidder constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

I want to auction a set of ASSETS (***A***) and fetch the maximum total price. The bidding is simultaneous and works as follows.

Say I have a collection of BIDDERS (***B***) who, individually, bid to purchase a subset of the assets ***A***. Each bidder is constrained by a maximum outlay which is typically less than the total price of their bids. I.e., Bidders can not generally purchase all the assets they bid on. They must settle on a subset as determined by the AUCTIONEER.

What method, algorithm or protocol can the auctioneer follow to ensure he fetches the MAXIMUM TOTAL PRICE? (Your ideal answer would include pseudocode.)

Fig 1. Matrix of assets and bids

```
              ASSETS -- (A)
         ---------------------------------------------
               A1    A2    A3    ...    Ai   ...    An
            +  --    --    --    ---    --   ---    --

BIDDERS  B1 | A1B1  A2B1  A3B1   ...   AiB1  ...   AnB1
(B)
         B2 | A1B2  A2B2  A3B2   ...   AiB2  ...   AnB2

         B3 | A1B3  A2B3  A3B3   ...   AiB3  ...   AnB3

        ... | ....  ....  ....   ...   ....  ...   ....

         Bj | A1Bj  A2Bj  A3Bj   ...   AiBj  ...   AnBj

        ... | ....  ....  ....   ...   ....  ...   ....

         Bm | A1Bm  A2Bm  A3Bm   ...   AiBm  ...   AnBm
```

Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, there is a similar assignment problem which [the Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) solves. [Here is an online implementation.](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php) However, that doesn't exactly solve this problem because more than one asset can be assigned to each bidder subject to their total outlay constraints.

Comment: get the maximum bid for each item and the total budget of each bidder, then solve a linear assignment problem

Comment: @LinAlg: I am an engineer, not a mathematician. I am unfamiliar with linear assignment problems. Could you please include some pseudocode and post a full answer if you are so inclined?

Comment: @LinAlg It'll be a bit more complex, because if one bidder outbids everyone all the time, you'll need to know the bids from other bidders when the big spender runs out of money. If you only have the maximum bid for each item, you only know what the big spender will spend and can't sell the items the big spender can't buy due to lack of information.

Comment: There is an algorithm called the hungarian algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: [Here is an online implementation of the Hungarian Algorithm.](http://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem). In general the GAP is NP-hard, but Wikipedia mentions a greedy approximate algorithm. You could also apply integer programming techniques to get approximate solutions.